# using cron to make php-script starting continuous processes

Tags: php, background, cron, nohup

I created a cronjob which call a php-script every 5mins.

This PHP script needs to start several other PHP CLI  scripts and keep them running in background even when the cron-script terminates.

I'm currently creating these sub-processes by the following line of code:

```
if (!$pid = shell_exec("nohup /var/[..]/cake.php test doSomething > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!")) return false;
```

When I call the "motherscript" via command-line everything's working great. But it seems like the sub-processes startet by the above line of code are terminated when the cron-job stops.

So how to spawn these `cake.php test doSomething`script and keep the child-process running under the predefined user in crontab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That makes sense, you need to tell the children PHP scripts to NOT terminate when it's parent stops.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Add the above line to the children PHP scripts.  Should do it

Comment: Sadly this didn't change anything

Comment: Excuse me - It did! I put it in the wrong file ;) Thanks a lot!